# Duplicate classes issue from multiple dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I was integrating the payment gateway and when I add payment library in gradle file and build project there is an error of duplicate classes. I tried looking for solutions in many places but I did not find the exact solution that will solve the issue, can you please help?

I have attached the output of logcat below

```
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldAttributes found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.6 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.6 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.FieldNamingStrategy found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.6 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.Gson found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.6 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
Duplicate class com.google.gson.GsonBuilder found in modules jetified-gson-2.8.6 (com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
..
..
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.detector.FinderPatternInfo found in modules jetified-ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3-runtime (:ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3:) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.BlockPair found in modules jetified-ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3-runtime (:ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3:) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.ByteMatrix found in modules jetified-ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3-runtime (:ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3:) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.Encoder found in modules jetified-ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3-runtime (:ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3:) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
Duplicate class com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder.MaskUtil found in modules jetified-ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3-runtime (:ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3:) and jetified-pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020-runtime (:pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020:)
```

My Gradle File

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation(project(path: ':barcode_detector')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.zxing', module: 'core'
    }

    implementation(name: 'ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3', ext: 'aar')
    implementation(name: 'MswipeWseriesUniversalDRDSDKVer1.0.27v3.7.3', ext: 'aar')
    implementation (name: 'pax_library_prod_v_1.0.0.3_03102020', ext: 'aar')

    implementation group: 'at.favre.lib', name: 'bcrypt', version: '0.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:' + retrofit_version
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:' + retrofit_version
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.5.0'
    implementation "com.appspector:android-sdk:1.4.1"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0-beta01"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"
//    implementation 'com.ezswype.card.payment.sdk:ezswype_release_sdk_2.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.kalmeshwargurav:projectbase:1.0.05'

    // CameraX
    def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta12"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"

    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX Lifecycle library
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"

    // If you want to additionally use the CameraX View class
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha23"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.0'

    // Firebase ML Kit dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:23.0.3'
    implementation 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.8'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.shitij.goyal:slide-button:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.chaos.view:pinview:1.4.1'

//    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
}
```

Comment: please show your gradle file

Comment: @LenaBru I updated my question with gradle file, you can check.

Comment: try replacing all the words "implementation" to "api", this should ignore duplicate dependencies

Comment: @LenaBru tried with ''api" but same issue is there

Comment: @KalmeshwarGurav have you get the solution for the duplicate class?